# Is it possible to get information about current user using google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Can my app javascript get information about the current user from google analytics e.g. a user logs into my app I want to determine his current location or previous events on ga so that I can show some of this information to the user.

Comment: Are you asking about the Google Analytics Realtime API? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/
What do you mean by "Current"

Comment: Yeah I think that might be what I am looking for. Will give it a go and let you know.